Fail to use boost 1.83 installed by Conan2 on C++ based executable, due to missing header 'cstddef'
I've got a project that uses boost library compiled and installed on my macOS build machine using conan2 under CMake.
I've managed to reproduce the problem using the following minimal code. my project is built out of the following files (residing in the same folder) :
main.cpp:
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
int main() {
    return 0;
}

conanfile.py (build+install the boost library):
from conan2 import ConanFile

class BoostExampleConan(ConanFile):
    name = "BoostExample"
    version = "1.0"
    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
    requires = "boost/1.83.0"  # Specify the Boost version you want
    generators = "CMakeDeps", "CMakeToolchain"
    default_options = {
        "boost/*:header_only": False
        "boost/*:with_stacktrace_backtrace"=False
        "boost/*:without_locale"=True
    }

    def layout(self):
        self.folders.source = "."
        self.folders.build = "build"

default profile settings (under /Users/user/.conan2/profiles/default)
[settings]
os=Macos
arch=armv8
compiler=apple-clang
compiler.version=16
compiler.cppstd=gnu17
compiler.libcxx=libc++
build_type=Release
compiler.cppstd=17
os=Macos

[buildenv]
CC=/usr/bin/clang
CXX=/usr/bin/clang++
CXXFLAGS=-stdlib=libc++
CFLAGS=-stdlib=libc++

CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(SingleCppBoostExample)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

include(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/conan.cmake)

conan_cmake_configure(
    REQUIRES boost/1.83.0
    GENERATORS CMakeDeps CMakeToolchain
)

conan_cmake_autodetect(settings)
set(CONAN_INSTALL_ARGS "--build=missing")

conan_cmake_install(
    PATH_OR_REFERENCE .
    SETTINGS ${settings}
    PROFILE default
    BUILD missing
)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -stdlib=libc++")

include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan_toolchain.cmake)

add_executable(my_boost_program main.cpp)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(my_boost_program Boost::system Boost::filesystem)

When running cmake --build . I get the following error :
In file included from /Users/user/Developer/BoostExampleConan/main.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/user/.conan2/p/b/boost694222cbc5cd8/p/include/boost/algorithm/string.hpp:18:
In file included from /Users/user/.conan2/p/b/boost694222cbc5cd8/p/include/boost/algorithm/string/std_containers_traits.hpp:18:
In file included from /Users/user/.conan2/p/b/boost694222cbc5cd8/p/include/boost/config.hpp:44:
/Users/user/.conan2/p/b/boost694222cbc5cd8/p/include/boost/config/detail/select_stdlib_config.hpp:26:14: fatal error: 'cstddef' file not found
   26 | #    include <cstddef>

Any ideas how to resolve it? do I need to set different compiler ?
Thanks

Have you checked other questions about the same error message? Googling for "fatal error: 'cstddef' file not found" finds e.g. that question.

Have you tried to take Boost out of the picture? Try changing #include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp> to the problematic line shown in the error message, #include <cstddef> (which is a standard header).
